# Is there anyway to show VirtualMachine after start it with VBoxHeadless?

Tags: virtualbox, ssh

I've installed a VirtualMachine to work on the background. I use SSH to control it via terminal. But, sometimes SSH service didn't work properly and I can't access the VirtualMachine outside. All I can do is power it off via VirtualBox GUI. But, I think it's not a good idea to use poweroff, since it's like I pull the power cable out. Is there anyway to show the VirtualMachine after I started it via VBoxHeadless? So, I can turn it off with `shutdown` command.

Comment: what about `VBoxManage controlvm <machine_name> acpipowerbutton ` command ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can not change the video output from headless to local screen after starting a Virtual Box VM in headless mode. But if not configured otherwise there will be an **RDP server** started automatically at default port 3389 in a headless machine. By this we will have access to that machine's GUI through any RDP-viewer.

In case SSH did not work it is very likely that your RDP server may be inaccessible too. In this case it is **not recommended** to poweroff or kill a running VM as this may lead to data loss.

In this case a quite convenient and secure workaround is to terminate the headless machine with saving the machine's state. This can also be done from the command line by:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "<Name of Machine>" savestate
```

After that we will be able to start the machine in non-headless mode at exactly the saved state from the Virtual Box Manager, or again from command line with:

```
VBoxManage startvm "<Name of Machine>"
```

Then we can debug the reason for any previously failed access, or safely shut down the machine.

Comment: Wow, so simple, so powerful... I wonder why I haven't think of, errr... not really a mystery. I wonder why I didn't read about this neat trick before.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it when I accidentally started a Saved State Normal Start in Headless. I simply saved the headless state again then did a normal start. My first inclination was to ssh into it, but this is much better.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)